# Order of operations when using evaluation bar

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have the function

\begin{align*}
f(x) = \sin(x)
\end{align*}

with first derivative

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \cos(x).
\end{align*}

If we evaluate $f'(x)$ at $x=0$, the result depends on whether you evaluate $f(0)$ or differentiate $f(x)$ first.

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}f(x)\mid_{x = 0} = \cos(x)\mid_{x = 0} = 1\\
\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}f(x)\mid_{x = 0} = \frac{d}{dx}f(0) = \frac{d}{dx}0 = 0
\end{align*}

**First question:** Does this mean the following two statements are not equivalent?

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)\mid_{x = 0}\\
\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)\mid_{x = 0}\right)
\end{align*}

**Second question:** if so, which of the following is true, and why?

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}f(x)\mid_{x = 0} =
\left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)\mid_{x = 0}
\end{align*}

or

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}f(x)\mid_{x = 0} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)\mid_{x = 0}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Suggestions for better tags are welcome. Couldn't find anything related to order of operations.

Comment: It's ambiguous; though, I'd assume it means evaluate the derivative at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. These are not equivalent indeed. $$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)\mid_{x = 0}\right)$$will always be 0.
2. For that reason, this notation always means the first form.

Answer (score 1):

If the following were true:
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\mid_{x = n} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)\mid_{x = n}\right)$$
Then it would *always* be 0. Why? Because once you evaluate a function of x at a particular value of x, it is no longer a function of x; it's a value (or, a constant function). The example (sin, cos) you gave is a little misleading. Consider instead the function $f(x)=x^2$ , and instead the point $x=3$ :

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\mid_{x = 0} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)\mid_{x = 0}\right)\\
f(x)\mid_{x = 0}=9\\
\frac{d}{dx}9=0$$